# Validate list of models programmatically in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-validation

I would like to validate list of models one by one programmatically.

I tried **TryValidateModel** but looks like it aggregates validation errors, so that when I iterate through the list of 10 models, if 5th model is not valid, for models 6-10 TryValidateModel returns **false**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use controller methods `ValidateModel` or `TryValidateModel`.

`ValidateModel` - throws exception if model is not valid.

`TryValidateModel` - returns bool which indicates if model is valid.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.mvc.controller.tryvalidatemodel%28v=vs.118%29.aspx):

> When a model is being validated, all validators for all properties are
>   run if at least one form input is bound to a model property. The
>   TryValidateModel is like the ValidateModel method except that the
>   TryValidateModel method does not throw an
>   InvalidOperationExceptionexception if the model validation fails.

If you validate *list of models* one by one, you probably would like to reset ModelState for each iteration by calling `ModelState.Clear()`.

Comment: Can this be done without the model having been populated by a view?  In other words your model object is populated in some other way.

Comment: @Matt yes, you can pass any model you wish into these methods

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me - I can call for(var o in viewModels) ..., ModelState.Clear() in each iteration, TryValidateObject(o, validation, validateResults), and so long as the first object is valid every single object after will pass as valid, even when I know for certain they're invalid.