# Asp.net MVC 5 model validation regex not validating special characters

Tags: asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have using ASP.NET MVC 5 and for validation I am using the regular Jquery unobtrusive validation library. 
Currently I am facing an issue, The regular expression validation is working all right on client side but on server side its not validating the value.

```
 [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]{19}$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Value")]
 public string Value{ get; set; }
```

this is the simple regular expression to validate 19 digits. Its working fine on client side it'll now allow `'` or `-` or any thing to pass on but if i submit directly to server than the model is not being validated. 
Do I need to do some thing special?

Comment: Are you calling Model.IsValid? What happens when the model binds? Any exception? Show us something else to help.

Comment: Some how ModelState.IsValid was not returning the error.

Answer (score 0):

ModelBinding ( the process of mapping post/get values to a complex model) occurs when you send  data via post/get/put/delete requests, if you are manually creating a class with validation classes somewhere those data/validation annotations won't apply.

**you can** validate models manually - [Validate list of models programmatically in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19994960/validate-list-of-models-programmatically-in-asp-net-mvc)

That said, there is a library called [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/) that can enforce those rules even when you are creating custom object/models outside of MVC ( [CodeContracts](http://doc.postsharp.net/##N_PostSharp_Patterns_Contracts) ) and if it doesn't validate it throws an exception. Keep in mind that this library is paid but it has free version available that might fit your needs.