# Validate an Object in ASP.NET MVC without passing it into an Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, modelstate

In ASP.NET MVC you can validate the model passed to an Action with `ModelState.IsValid()`.

I'd like to validate arbitrary objects rather than the one Model passed in. How can I do that, using the framework's libraries?

```
public ActionResult IsValidSoFar()
{
    // Get a user's autosaved data
    var json = await ...
    HomeModel model = JsonConvert.Deserialize<HomeModel>(json);

    // Validate the model <---- How?        
}

public class HomeModel
{
    [Required, MaxLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why is you parameter `string model` instead of `HomeModel model? The `DefaultModelBinder` will deserialize it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use ValidationContext class ... like below

```
var context = new ValidationContext(modelObject);
    var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
    var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(modelObject, context, results);

    if (!isValid)
    {
        foreach (var validationResult in results)
        {
            //validation errors
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello @Sam.C this was exactly what I'm looking for, thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

You can use ValidateModel or TryValidateModel controller methods.

- **ValidateModel** - throws exception if model is not valid.
- **TryValidateModel** - returns bool which indicates if model is valid.

IMPORTANT: If you validate **list of models** one by one, you probably would like to reset ModelState for each iteration by calling **ModelState.Clear()**;

Please see my question regarding this: [Validate list of models programmatically in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19994960/validate-list-of-models-programmatically-in-asp-net-mvc)