# C# ASP.NET Core 5.0 MVC : validate a list of models created programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, ienumerable, model-validation

**Overview**

I'm working on a project where I ingest a CSV file, where each record results in the creation of a model in the back end. After ingestion, I am able to create a list of models, and I can return the list of models back to the view with no issue.

However, I want to do custom validation on each model in the list and return the validation results to the view. In this example, I have custom model validation that checks if the email already exists via a database check. When I am creating a model one at a time through a Form on a view, everything goes well. All the validation is run, and there are no issues.

**Problem**

The issue is when I programmatically create `List<Person>()`, and then try to validate each `Person` model in the list. What ends up happening is all the errors are aggregated and when I return the list to the view and display in table via `foreach(var p in Model.PersonList)`, with `@Html.ValidationSummary()`, then each table row shows all the errors of all the models, not just the errors that pertain to that `PersonModel`.

Within a foreach loop, I call `TryValidateModel()` and follow it with `ModelState.Clear()`, but this does not help. I've also tried using `ModelState.Clear()` at the beginning of the foreach loop, again no help.

Simplified code of what I'm doing and where I'm stuck.

Controller code - root of problem is here in the foreach loop:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult BulkModelCreation(BulkUpload inputCSV)
{
   // No issue here, I successfully convert CSV to data table. Each Record represents a model 
   // If there are 10 records in the CSV, then I will have a list of 10 People
   DataTable dt = CSVHelper.CSVToDataTable(inputCSV.InputFile);
  
   List<Person> people = new List<Person>();

   if (dt != null)
   {  
      // My issues is located here, I think
      // In the foreach loop, I read each row from the DataTable, and create a new Person Model
      // I want to validate each PersonModel and then add Person to people list
      foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
      {
         // Create new person
         Person p = new Person();
         p.FirstName = dr["FirstName"].ToString();
         p.LastName = dr["LastName"].ToString();
         // More model attributes
         p.Email = dr["Email"].ToString();

         // Validate the model, and the validation works
         TryValidateModel(p);

         people.add(p);

         // This is where I am unsure of what to do
         //To try and reset for the next PersonModel in the List, but this does not work. 
         // If any person in the list has a duplicate email, then all items in the list will show
         // as having a duplicate email.
         ModelState.Clear();
      }   
   }   

   // Other stuff, create model to be returned that has an attribute that is a List<People>
   ModelToReturn ModelReturn = new ModelToReturn();
   ModelReturn.Persons = people;

   // Obj is returned, and data is populated. No issue here
   return View(ModelReturn)
}
```

Simplified model class:

```
public class PersonModel
{
    [Required]
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    [Required]
    public string LastName {get;set;}
    // More stuff
    //Custom Valiation
    [EmailValidation]
    public string Email {get;set;]
}
```

Custom validation:

```
public class EmailValidationAttribute: ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var PersonModel = (PersonModel)validationContext.ObjectInstance;
        // Passing in Person Repository service so that I can check the db if email already exists
        var service = (IPersonRepository)validationContext.GetService(typeof(IPersonRepository));
        bool isDuplicate = service.CheckDuplicate(PersonModel.Email);

        if (isDuplicate)
        {
            return new ValidationResult("Email Already Exists");
        }
        else
        {
             return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
    }       
}
```

Simplified view:

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">First Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
      <th scope="col">More Stuff</th>
      <th scope="col">Email</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach(var p in Model.Persons)
    {
    <tr>
      <td>
         <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control" />
      </td>
      <td>
         <input asp-for="LastName" class="form-control" />
      </td>
      <td>MORE STUFF</td>
      <td>
         <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
             @Html.ValidationSummary()<!-- if one person has a duplicate email, then this will say 'Duplicate Email' for every single record in Model.Persons-->
      </td>
     </tr>
    }
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Note, I have reviewed and tried what was suggested in this post: [Validate list of models programmatically in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19994960/validate-list-of-models-programmatically-in-asp-net-mvc)

But that does not work, either for the OP, and myself. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You'll need a more customized validation. Keep a dictionary of record id (row id) and its corresponding validation object then the view will need to parse and display the errors per record. I may be useful to map to a new model PersonResponseModel which will probably be very similar to PersonModel but with your error property and omit further validation attributes. Or wrap the person list in a TransactionResponseModel with properties related to the transaction (status, errors, etc.).

Comment: Thanks @Jasen that's what I ended up doing and it worked out.